# How do I store an array of objects in a cookie with jQuery $.cookie()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have a list of javascript objects:

```
var people = [
   { 'name' : 'Abel', 'age' : 1 },
   { 'name' : 'Bella', 'age' : 2 },
   { 'name' : 'Chad', 'age' : 3 },
]
```

I tried to store them in a browser cookie with jQuery $.cookie():

```
$.cookie("people", people);
```

I then retrieve this cookie and then try to push another object into it:

```
var people = $.cookie("people");
people.push(
    { 'name' : 'Daniel', 'age' : 4 }
);
```

However, this does not work; I analyzed this code in Firebug, and Console noted that `people` was a string (`"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"`) and that the push function did not exist.

What is going on? What is the proper way to store and retrieve a list of objects?

Comment: you should change the var name of `people` to `babies` :)

Comment: $.cookie( "people", $.param(people) );  This worked perfectly to me

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Cookies can only store strings. Therefore, you need to convert your array of objects into a JSON string. If you have the JSON library, you can simply use `JSON.stringify(people)` and store that in the cookie, then use `$.parseJSON(people)` to un-stringify it.

In the end, your code would look like:

```
var people = [
   { 'name' : 'Abel', 'age' : 1 },
   { 'name' : 'Bella', 'age' : 2 },
   { 'name' : 'Chad', 'age' : 3 },
];
$.cookie("people", JSON.stringify(people));
// later on...
var people = $.parseJSON($.cookie("people"));
people.push(
    { 'name' : 'Daniel', 'age' : 4 }
);
$.cookie("people", JSON.stringify(people));
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the JSON library?

Comment: found this very helpful but this var people = $.parseJSON($.cookie("people");) should be this var people = $.parseJSON($.cookie("people"));  ";" is out of place.

Comment: @ARWVISIONS better? Hard to tell, on a mobile device.

Answer (score 7):

I attempted this today and could not get it to work. Later i found out that it was because I had 3 very large objects which I tried to save in a cookie.

The way I worked arround this was by storing the information in the browsers local storage.

example:

```
localStorage.setItem("test2", JSON.stringify(obj) )

localStorage.getItem("test2")
```

further info about local storage: [cookies vs local storage](http://people.rit.edu/tlh4225/736/exercises/storageWriteup.html)

4 hours of my time vent to this, dont make the same mistake.